# error: too many connections for role "databaseName"

Tags: node.js, postgresql

[image]I am using typeorm datasource to connect to elephantsql postgres, been getting this issue, can anyone help with the fix

```
error: too many connections for role "databaseName"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
    at Parser.parse (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 110,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '53300',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'miscinit.c',
  line: '661',
  routine: 'InitializeSessionUserId'
}
```

Comment: Did the error message really mention a role name which differs from the one you are configured to connect to?

Comment: on a side note, you may now want to change the user/password (don't just delete the code picture)

Answer (score 0):

Free ElephantSQL databases accept only 1 connection. Try changing the pool setting `extra.max` to 1:

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  // ...postgresConfig
  extra: {
    max: 1, // set pool max size
  }
});
```